# Change out of stock/in stock text color

Tags: css, woocommerce

Single Product page displays In stock/ Out of stock; both Text = red.
I need to change In stock = green, and Out of stock remain red.

Help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
p.stock.out-of-stock {
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

and

```
p.stock.in-stock {
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

into the Custom CSS and adjusting the Hex code accordingly.

Not sure how to delete my question but maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that only with css but you can do this with JavaScript and a api.

For example this is a html

```
<div>
   <p class="stock">Stock</p>
</div>

JavaScript


var stock = document.querySelector('.stock');
    function countProducts(){
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/stock')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                if (myJson != 0) {
                    stock.style.color= 'green';
                 }else{
                    stock.style.color = 'red';
                }
            });
    }
```

But if you want to know how to do it in css. It's like this

HTML

```
   <div>
       <p class="stock">Stock</p>
       <p class="NoStock"> No Stock </p>
    </div>


    //If there is a stock
    .stock{
     color: 'green';
     display: inherit;
    }

    .noStock{
      color: 'red';
      display : 'none';
    }

    //If there is  not a stock

    .noStock{
     color: 'red';
     display: 'inherit';
    }

    .stock{
     color: green;
     display: 'none';
    }
```

Comment: I answered my own question above with the working solution for my oceanwp website.